# Plotting a histogram or any other type of graph in Python 3 from created frequency dictionaries with use of Pandas

Tags: excel, python-3.x, dictionary, matplotlib, plot

I have a question, I don't know why I always have problems with plotting anything in Python and in any programming languages in general, I only manage to plot thins well in excel...

Here is the deal, I have data from an excel sheet, from every column in the sheet I create a dictionary of frequencies.

When I type the following:

```
frequency_dictionary.get('Year')
```

where 'Year' is the name of a column I get this information in the console

```
{1976.0: 91,
 1973.0: 54,
 1968.0: 74,
 1962.0: 62,
 1977.0: 58,
.
.
.
 1992.0: 1,
 'Missing Value': 389}
```

I want to plot this information into a histogram or any other type of graph to have a better picture for every column i decide to test out.
I tried this code:

```
dff = pd.DataFrame([frequency_dictionary.get('BirthYear')])
dff = dff.T
dff.hist()
```

But the histogram looks nothing like the data I am looking at.
My X values are from 0-400 the y values are from 0 to 25

Any quick ways to plot this sort of data?
I need something that I would just change the column name and get data for the other columns.
Hope I made myself clear.
Thanks in advance for any advice.

Your are right about bar over histogram, but that is why I said any type of graph that would be best suitable for this.
The duplicate question that this is marked as I tried the code they propose, but it does not work.

```
df.plot.bar(x="Sex", y="Survived")

plt.show()
```

When I used this and wrote that I want the "Year" column it puts the Years as X and Y is two other columns from the whole dictionary, instead of using the frequencies of each year that is stored in the 'Year' dictionary, so I am still not sure how to solve my problem with the use of that plotting method

**The duplicate did not answer my question at all**, good that I figure it out myself, and if anyone needs it here it is:

```
dictionary = frequency_dictionary.get(dColumn)
plt.bar(range(len(dictionary)), dictionary.values(), align='center')
plt.xticks(range(len(dictionary)), dictionary.keys())
plt.show()
```

Where dColumn is a string value of a column in the frequency dictionaries

Comment: Is there a good generic question which asks for a histogram where instead a bar plot is needed? Best one, which also clearly explains why a histogram is not a bar plot. I feel like this is coming up every couple of days and I always have problems finding a good duplicate.